# Check if string is repetition of an unknown substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to solve the same problem in javascript with regexp mentioned here: [Check if string is repetition of an unknown substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184123/check-if-string-is-repetition-of-an-unknown-substring)

I translated the regex in the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7184872/1463159) to Javascript: `^(.+){2,}$`
But it does not work as I expect:

```
'SingleSingleSingle'.replace(/^(.+){2,}$/m, '$1')  // returns 'e' instead of exptected 'Single'
```

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I currently have no explanation for why it returns `e`, but `.` matches any character and `.{2,}` basically just means "match any two or more characters".

What you want is to match whatever you captured in the capture group, by using backreferences:

```
/^(.+)\1+$/m
```

---

I just noticed that this is also what the answer you linked to suggests to use: `/(.+)\1+/`. The expression is exactly the same, there is nothing you have to change for JavaScript.

Comment: Because of the '^' and '$' I suppose `^(.+){2,}$` should match the whole string.
Maybe the greediness or laziness of the quantifiers could explain the situation - but it seems weird to me.

However your solution is okay. (I misunderstood the Ruby example: I supposed it uses a quantifier in an alternative syntax than in JS.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why you get 'e' is that `{2,}` implies two or more repetitions of a match to the regex that preceeds it, in this case `(.+)` . `{2,}` does not guarantee that the repetitions match ***each other***, only that they all qualify as a match for `(.+)`.

From what I can see (using [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)) it looks like the first match to 
`(.+)` is 'SingleSingleSingl' (due to greedy matching) and the second match is 'e'. Since capturing groups only remember their last match, that is why replace() is giving you back 'e'. If you use `(.+?)` (for non-greedy or reluctant matching) each individual character will match, but you will still only get the last one, 'e'.

Using a back reference, as Felix mentioned, is the only way that I know of to guarantee that the repetitions match each other.